# NUXTJS | Error on loading css / layout the first call

Tags: html, css, vue.js, layout, nuxt.js

I am playing as a newbie with Nuxtjs. I bought an html template to transform it as Nuxtjs project. The template, there are several css to display out a good layout.

There are issues on loading a `page.vue` as first call but if I reload it, the `layout/css` are displayed correctly.

My tries were:
 - Adding css: [ ... ] at `nuxt.config.js` as global.
 - Added css as script injected into the `page.vue` as follow:

```
export default {
  head () {
    return {
      link: [
        { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: './css/animate.css' },
        { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: './css/et-line.css' },
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

I appreciate your clues & tricks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your css files to `assets` or `static` folder. More info about the difference you could find in the doc: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets#static
2. Plug it in `nuxt.config.js` as so:
   `css: ["~assets/main.css"]` or `css: ["~/static/static.css"]`
3. Rebuild the project